# error in configuring pure master/slave configuration in activemq 5.8?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, messaging, messagebroker

I 'am trying to configure pure master/slave broker configuration. In slave activemq.xml file I have following configuration

```
<services>
    <masterConnector remoteURI="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</services>
```

When I start slave broker it gives me following error:

> Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Line 50 in
>   XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml] is invalid;
>   nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 50;
>   columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
>   starting with element 'masterConnector'. One of
>   '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":broker,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core

I have also tried to configure it by specifying masterConnectorURI attribute directly on broker element but still i get SAXException. Everywhere on internet same method is given and documentation of activemq on official site seems they are not updating it. Thanks in advance

Comment: after much searching i found a link which says that pure master/slave configuration has been removed from version 5.8.0. maybe that is the reason i'am getting parsing excpetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure master slave configuration feature was removed in 5.8.0, see the note at the top of [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/pure-master-slave.html).  There are still plenty of other options available though, see the [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html).